# The Alabama Sitecore User Group: Sep 28, 2017 (Birmingham, AL USA)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

This is the first Sitecore usergroup in Alabama!

We have an impressive lineup of Sitecore Professionals and a Sitecore MVP on the list to speak.

This is a chance to put ALABAMA on the map in regards to the Sitecore community as well as gathering like IT professionals in the community to share with one another about our experiences in web development.

Speakers:

- Corey Smith, Sitecore Architect and MVP, will be there to discuss
  Sitecore MVC from A-Z
- Keith McCormick, Sitecore Architect, will be there to discuss the
  Sitecore do's and don'ts

**Time/Date**:

> Thursday, September 28, 2017
>
> 6:30 PM to 8:30 PM EST (10:30 PM to 12:30 AM UTC)

**Location**:

> Courtyard by Marriott Birmingham Colonnade/Grandview
>
> 4300 Colonnade Parkway,
>
> Birmingham, AL

Details at [Alabama Sitecore User Group Meetup](https://www.meetup.com/Alabama-Sitecore-User-Group/events/241267996/) page

Comment: Include UTC times please.